# What plant is this? My wife is saying it is an aromatic/garden plant

Tags: identification

My wife is telling me that she bought it as aromatic garden plant 
It is now 3-4ft tall and blocking the view of a rose behind it

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks VERY much like wild parsnip, which is a plant you need to remove as soon as you can.Here are some images to help with the ID:

- [Leaves](https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/udata/r9ndp23q/pd/pastinaca-sativa-rosette.jpg)
- [Stalk](https://www.mda.state.mn.us/sites/default/files/inline-images/wplfstm.jpg)
- [Flowers (umbels)](https://seasonsflow.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/wild-parsnip1.jpg). Note that this site minimizes the risks of this plant.

If this is wild parsnip, it's an invasive and potentially dangerous plant, so BE CAREFUL when removing it! The sap is phytotoxic and will cause chemical burns if it gets on your skin in the sunlight. The sap can also cause damage to your eyes. To remove the plant, wear long sleeves and gloves (and eye protection, if possible), cut the plant down to the ground (and dispose of it in a garbage bag), then dig out the root. This is nasty stuff that you do NOT want to set seed.

EDIT - It's possible that the person/store where you wife bought the plant thought that it was Golden Alexanders - it's certainly NOT that plant.

Comment: yes it was parsnip. Incredibly shallow roots for a plant that big. Not sure it if was the wild one. My wife use a large garden pair of scissors to remove the upper plan and then my shovel did the rest. very interleaved roots and twisted She wore gloves I did not, we are both OK I am glad is gone because it was masking a rose that we thought it  turned wild because the root took over. To our surprise it is a climbing rose that is full of flowers everywhere this year  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGZRD.jpg  I will update the thread I posted here a year or two ago with a picture of this year

Answer (score 1):

Looks a bit like Lovage (*Levisticum officinale*). To know for sure you can try to smell the leaves, break it in your fingers, and if it smells like a soup broth it is Lovage.

Comment: I does not have a smell or taste like lovage

Comment: added more pictures, I wish it was Lovage ...

Comment: Maybe it's parsnip then instead...

Comment: That doesn't look like lovage

Comment: @adrian it's parsnip, see op's comments

Answer (score -1):

That looks exactly like dill flower to me, and the height is in the 2-4 foot range that dill grows... But the large green leaves look unfamiliar. Is it possible they are two separate plants?